# Proof that $\sum_{i=1}^{i=3} \sum_{j=1}^{j=3} A_{ij} \delta_{ji} = A_{ij}$

Tags: matrices, tensors

Can someone provide a proof that $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{i=3} \displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{j=3} A_{ij} \delta_{ji} =A_{ij}$? I know that the Kronecker delta is identified with the identity matrix, but I can only make sense of that with vectors, not with matrices.

Comment: Can you do one of the sums? Say, $\sum_{j=1}^3 A_{ij}\delta_{jk}$?

Comment: There is a problem. To me your sum is $$A_{11}+A_{22}+A_{33}\neq A_{ij}.$$ Moreover, the left side is not dependent of $ij$, then where come from $ij$ in the right side ? ou didn't define them !

Comment: @idm that's what I thought, but I thought I was told $\delta_{ij}$ was the identity matrix, i.e. $a_i\delta_{ij}=a_j$

Comment: Also I think I've been confused, I just learned index notation in my physics class.

Comment: May be, there is a mistakes in your assignment :-)